# How to pass a list of objects to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, list

Im writing a function that should receive a list of book objects as an argument. In each book object there is a private data member price. The function is suppose to compare the prices of each book and return the book with the highest price.

```
//Client program
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
#include "textbook.h"
#include "Name.h"
#include "unsorted.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

book b1("The Exception to the Rulers", "Amy", "Goodman", "Hyperion", 342, "1-4013-0131", 21.95,'N'); // this is the title, authors first & last name, publisher, number of pages, isbn number, price, and code.
book b2("Who moved my cheese", "Spencer", "Johnson", "Red Tree", 95, "0-399-14446-3", 19.99,  'H');
book b3("Hellbound Hearts", "Neil", "Gaiman", "Dark Harvest", 326, "978-1-4391-4090-1", 16.00, 'F');

UnsortedType L1; // creating a list "L1" with the default vaule lengh 0

L1.InsertItem(b1); // populating the list with the first book
L1.InsertItem(b2); // populating the list with the second book
L1.InsertItem(b3); // populating the list with the third book
```

In the main im not really sure how to pass the actual list "L1" or the contents of L1 to the function that will compare the prices. I guess im getting confused because in order to call the function getMostExpensive I would do some thing like:

```
L1.getMostExpensive();
```

but if i call my function with L1 do I have to pass any args, and if not then how do I access the private data member price inside of the function getMostExpensive()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should `price` be a private member of `book`? Seems to me like "everyone" should be able to know a book's price...

If you can indeed make it public, why not use a simpler `std::vector<book>` with a free function `getMostExpensive()`?

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<book> L1; 

L1.push_back(b1); // include first book
L1.push_back(b2); // include second book
L1.push_back(b3); // include third book

...

// free function
book getMostExpensive(const std::vector<book>& b) {

    double maxPrice=0;
    unsigned int maxInd;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<b.size(); ++i){
        if (b[i].price > maxPrice){
            maxInd = i;
            maxPrice = b[i].price;
        }
    }
    return b[maxInd];
}
```

If you must keep `price` `private`, you can make `UnsortedType` a `friend` of `book`:

```
class UnsortedType;
class book {
    ...
    friend class UnsortedType;
    ...
};
```

in which case `L1` has access to the privates of `book`.

My default rule of thumb however is that whenever I need `friend`'s, there's a flaw in my design :p

You could also use a getter/setter approach:

```
class book 
{
private:
    double _price; // the actual price

public: 
    const double& price // read-only copy of price

    // constructor
    book(...);

    // price-setter
    void setPrice(double newPrice);

};

// constructor initializes const reference to private member _price
book::book(...) : price(_price) {...}

void book::setPrice(double newPrice) { _price = newPrice>=0.0?newPrice:0.0; }

...

int main(...){
    book b;
    ...
    double P = b.price;  // valid
    b.price = 56.8;      // NOT valid; compile-time error

    b.setPrice(56.8);    // valid; this is the only way to set the price

}
```

Comment: we havent covered vectors or friends yet, and we arent suppose to use concepts that we havent covered in class yet :( I guess I need to go learn about vectors asap cause I see them frequently used.

Comment: @terencevaughn: Aha...well, see my edit :) Are these techniques permissible?

Comment: yea this is what i have in my book file for the most part, my problem is in the main, after i have built my list of books how do I pass that list into my getMostExpensive() function?

Comment: @terencevaughn: Also, if your teacher is any good, s/he should be more than happy with students going out of their way to learn new techniques (not unlike yourself).

Comment: @terencevaughn: the same as the vector: `book getMostExpensive(const UnsortedType& L1) {...}`. You know what the `const ...&` part means, yes? And then use the function like so: `getMostExpensive(L1);`...or should it be a member function of `UnsortedType`?

Comment: yea, & means your passing by address. right? And yes getMostExpensive is member of UnsortedType

Comment: @terencevaughn: So, what does the function `InsertItem` do? How do you store items in the `UnsortedType` class?

Comment: InsertItem adds objects to the list.                                   void UnsortedType::InsertItem(book item)
{
 info[length] = item;
 length++ ;
}

Comment: @terencevaughn: Well, then you can just use the function I wrote for `std::vector<book>`, but then with `std::list<book>`, and make it a member function of `UnsortedType`. Then the private data member `price` can be solved by either method I described above.

Comment: hey man sorry about the late response. It still isn't working for me, i even tried to store my objects in a vector but im still unable to access price because its a private member of book.h and my list is built through UnsortedType.

Comment: @terencevaughn: Then 1) make `price` `public`, or 2) make a public accessor to the `private` member `price`, or 3) make `UnsortedType` a `friend class` of `book`, or 4) overload `operator>` and/or `operator<` and/or `operator>=` etc. in class `book`, which takes another book as input argument and compares the books prices. Then you can `std::sort` them, find the `max` and `min`., etc.

Comment: ok I got the function    getMostExpensive() to compile without any errors, and I used a vector to store the books. The only other problem im having is when I pass the vector in the main I get an error: use of undeclared identifier 'getMostExpensive'. what could be causing this?